# How to reference table name in DBT Model (GitHub)

Tags: sql, github, dbt

How do I reference the table name (highlighted cursor) from a csv file in DBT Model (GitHub)?

My current yml file only has "models: ...".

[image]

The csv file to be referenced is named orders.csv, uploaded under tables -> datawarehouse folder.

Comment: do you want to reference this file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're referring to a [seed](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/seeds), which is a feature where dbt can create a table in your warehouse using a `.csv` file that is stored alongside the code in your project.

After you add the `.csv` file to your `seeds` directory inside your project (or some other directory nested under `/seeds/`), you run `dbt seed` in your terminal to create the table from the data in the CSV. From your example, let's say the CSV is called `orders.csv` and is located at `/seeds/tables/datawarehouse/orders.csv`.

After that, you can select from the seed in other models by using `ref` with the seed's filename, so `{{ ref('orders') }}`.

If you are using another tool (not `dbt seed`) to upload the CSV, you need to find the location of the table in your data warehouse, and then add that location as a [`source`](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/sources), and you will specify the database/schema/table name in the `sources.yml` file. If you have the table defined as a source, you select from it with `{{ source('my_source', 'my_table') }}`.